# Python: how to discern if a path is within another path?

Tags: python, path

I need to know if pathA is a subset of, or is contained within pathB.

I'm making a little script that will walk some old volumes and find duplicate files. My general approach (and even if it's a bad one for it's inefficiency, it's just for me and it works, so I'm ok with the brute-forceness of it) has been:

1. Map all the files to a log
2. Create a hash for all the files in the log
3. Sort the hash list for duplicates
4. Move the duplicates somewhere for inspection prior to deletion

I want to be able to exclude certain directories, though (ie. System files). This is what I've written:

```
#self.search_dir =  top level directory to be searched for duplicates
#self.mfl        =  master_file_list, being built by this func, a list of all files in search_dir
#self.no_crawl_list   =  list of files and directories to be excluded from the search
def build_master_file_list(self):
        for root, directories, files in os.walk(self.search_dir):
            files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']
            directories[:] = [d for d in directories if not d[0] == '.']
            for filename in files:
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                if [root, filepath] in self.no_crawl_list:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.mfl.write(filepath + "\n")
        self.mfl.close()
```

But I'm pretty sure this isn't going to do what I'd intended. My goal is to have *all subdirectories* of anything in  `self.no_crawl_list` excluded as well, such that:

if
 `/path/to/excluded_dir` is added to `self.no_crawl_list`

then paths like `/path/to/excluded_dir/sub_dir/implicitly_excluded_file.txt`

will be skipped as well.  I think my code is currently being entirely literal about what to skip. Short of exploding the path parts and comparing them to every possible combination in `self.no_crawl_list`, however, I don't know how to do this. 'Lil help? :)

Comment: You could turn both paths (the current path and the paths in the blacklist) to normalized, absolute paths using [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), and then simply check for `if any(subpath in path for subpath in blacklist_paths)`. This will still only do substring matching, but it should be reasonably correct since `os.path.abspath` will ensure you're only dealing with absolute paths with no double slashes.

Comment: bam, nice hack, that'll do!

Comment: things to watch out for: Case-insensitive filesystems (see [`os.path.normcase()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase)) and symbolic links (see [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath)). If you'd like to bundle up whatever's relevant for your usecase in a `is_subdir(a, b)` function and post that as a self-answer, I'd be happy to upvote that ;-)

Comment: Actually, `path.startswith(subpath)` would be the proper check, `subpath in path` could give false-positives.

Answer (score 1):

As per the assistance of [Lukas Graf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599111/lukas-graf) in the comments above, I was able to build this and it works like a charm:

```
def is_subpath(self, path, of_paths):
        if isinstance(of_paths, basestring): of_paths = [of_paths]
        abs_of_paths = [os.path.abspath(of_path) for of_path in of_paths]
        return any(os.path.abspath(path).startswith(subpath) for subpath in abs_of_paths)
```

Also, this currently doesn't account for symlinks and assumes a UNIX filesystem, see comments in original question for advice on extending this.

Comment: BTW: See [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for the `[foo(a) for a in lst]` syntax, and [generator epxressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) for the similar expression inside the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) call (basically the same thing, but *lazy*).